# How to Enable and Disable Form Controls based on values in selected dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 drop down list that are dependent on one another.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusId, "StatusId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("StatusId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group DeclineReasonId">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeclineReasonId, "DeclineReasonId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("DeclineReasonId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeclineReasonId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group PendingReasonsId">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PendingReasonsId, "PendingReasonsId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("PendingReasonsId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PendingReasonsId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

The values that populates in the dropdownlist with the label StatusId is "Pending", "Declined", "Approved".
if i choose "Pending", "DeclineReasonId" should be disabled .
if i choose "Declined", "PendingReasonsId" should be disabled.
if i choose "Approved", Both DeclineReasonId and PendingReasonsId should be disabled.

If after choosing any of the three and before submitting i decide to change the StatusId, I want it to be able to adjust such that

If i change from Pending to Declined - PendingReasonsId should be disabled and DeclineReasonId should be enabled
if i change from Pending to Approved - PendingReasonsId and DeclineReasonsId should be disabled

if i change from Declined to Pending - DeclineReasonId should be disabled and PendingReasonsId be enabled
if i change form Declined to Approved - Both DeclineReasonId and PendingReasonsId be disabled

if i change from Approved to Pending - PendingReasonsId should be enabled and DeclineReasonsId be disabled
if i change from Approved to Declined - DeclinedReasonId should be enabled and PendingReasonId be left in Disabled state.

Currently ive tried the code below but it doesnt seem to work perfectly

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StatusId").focusout(function () {
            //$("#PendingReasonsId").removeAttr("disabled");
            //$("#DeclineReasonId").hide("disabled", "disabled");

            var StatusValue = $("#StatusId").children("option").filter(":selected").text();
            //alert(StatusValue);
            if (StatusValue == "Declined") {
                $("#PendingReasonsId").attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
            else if (StatusValue == "Pending") {
                $("#DeclineReasonId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            else if (StatusValue == "Approved") {
                $("#PendingReasonsId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#DeclineReasonId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }

        })
        $("#StatusId").change(function () {
            var Value = $("#StatusId").children("option").filter(":selected").text()
            if(Value == "Pending")
            {
                $("#PendingReasonsId").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#DeclineReasonId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            else if (Value == "Declined") {
                $("#DeclineReasonId").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#PendingReasonsId").attr("disabled", "disabled");

            }
            else if (Value == "Approved") {
                $("#PendingReasonsId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#DeclineReasonId").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: Is it something you would like to achieve?

https://jsfiddle.net/w9oL29x3/

Comment: The fact that you have `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` associated with each dropdown suggests those properties have validation attributes. Disabling a control means it wont post back, therefore validation will fail and `ModelState` will be invalid, so doing this does not seem to make sense. Also recommend you use `.prop('disabled', true)` and `.prop('disabled', false)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke not all the controls in the form are required, except for the statusId which is required,the other dropdown lists are nullable, so i dont think it will affect the ModelState.  PS: its been a long time sire!

Comment: In that case, you should remove the ` @Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for the non required properties.

Comment: @StephenMuecke will do that, but with regards to my question, why does my jquery code not work?

Comment: @ibnhamza, Haven't had a chance to look at it in detail so not sure - I copy it into a test project tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks will be expecting but in the meantime i will keep working on it. By the way are you the same Stephen Muecke referenced here? -->  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Muecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke I dont know if it's appropiate but i will like to meet you one way or the other. I need serious mentoring with my C# and asp.net and you've proven to be an helpful personality to me so far. That will make my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following code should work for you. The change event first disables both the Pending Reasons and Declined Reasons dropdowns, then enables one or the other (or neither) depending on selected Status. Note the `.focusout` function is not required.

```
var pending = $('#PendingReasonId'); // cache elements
var declined = $('#DeclinedReasonId');
declined.prop('disabled', true); // initial status is Pending so disable DeclinedReasons

// Handle the selected status
$('#StatusId').change(function () {
  var status = $("#StatusId").children("option").filter(":selected").text(); // get selected value
  // disable both
  pending.prop('disabled', true);
  declined.prop('disabled', true);
  if (status == 'Pending') {      
    pending.prop('disabled', false); // enable PendingReasons
  } else if (status == 'Declined') {    
    declined.prop('disabled', false); // enable DeclinedReasons
  }
});
```

Side notes
Disabling a control means that its value will not be posted back so you should not have any validation attributes (other than a `[RequiredIf]` or similar conditional type attribute) associated with the `PendingReasonId` and `DeclinedReasonId` properties. Therefore you can remove the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` associated with these properties.

Comment: that didnt work. Here you said "initial status is Pending so disable DeclinedReasons", this is not so because i used this script below to ensure that when the page loads the default value that will be shown in the dropdown in not any of the three but null to ensure that if a user tries to edit it wont post anything except if the user selects it. ("#StatusId").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");$("#DeclineReasonId").prepend("<option value=''selected='selected'></option>");
   $("#PendingReasonsId").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");

Comment: What! - perhaps you should have mentioned that before! and why would you do that anyway instead of using the overload of `DropDownList` that adds the option label automatically. All you have done is include a pointless and bad script that screws up model binding.

Comment: omg! the same form that handles the creation is used to edit it if the status  changes from perhaps pending to approved. as a result, if the default values in the drop down shows on load of the page it will postback all the values shown in the dropdown and that was why i opted for that script. Would find a way.

Comment: Use the overload that accepts a label option (which renders the `null` option so you get proper binding), then the first line of the script should be `$('#StatusId').trigger('change);` and delete the `declined.prop('disabled', true);` line. Also use the strongly typed helpers `@Html.DropDownListFor()`